# Check if twitter username exists

Tags: authentication, twitter, oauth, exists

Is there a way to check if a twitter username exists?
Without being authenticated with OAuth or the twitter basic authentication?

Comment: If you want to be a good citizen to the remote website you're apparently relying upon for your service, you're most likely going to want to do this using the published API and OAuth.  With them, user lookup is dead easy: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-users-lookup  And implementing OAuth is quite easy too since there are existing libraries to simplify the process http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/OAuth_Ruby_Tutorial -- We're talking five extra lines in your application.  -- If you automate this outside the API, you risk getting rate limited/blocked by Twitter.

Comment: you should reselect the chosen answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: This API is not available since 2012.

According to the api docs you can pass an email address to the user/
show method, I would assume that if a user didn't exist you'd get back
a 404, which should allow you to determine whether or not the user
exists.

eg: http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?email=t...@example.com

result if not exist :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<hash> 
  <request>/users/show.xml?email=tur...@example.com</request> 
  <error>Not found</error> 
</hash
```

Comment: The issue is I don't have their email address.

Comment: The Twitter API no longer supports lookup by email address.

Answer (score 28):

UPDATE 2021: This API is not available.

As of right now, you're better off using the API the signup form uses to check username availability in realtime. Requests are of the format:

```
https://twitter.com/users/username_available?username=whatever
```

And give you a JSON response with a `valid` key giving you a true if the username can be registered:

```
{"valid":false,"reason":"taken","msg":"Username has already been taken","desc":"That username has been taken. Please choose another."}
{"valid":true,"reason":"available","msg":"Available!","desc":"Available!"}
{"valid":false,"reason":"is_banned_word","msg":"Username is unavailable","desc":"The username \"root\" is unavailable. Sorry!"}
```

The reason this is better than checking for 404 responses is that sometimes words are reserved (like 'root' above), or a username is actually taken but for some reason the account is gone from the Twitter front end.

Comment: The only issue with this solution is that the endpoint you're attempting to invoke is undocumented and unsupported, and your app will be in danger of being blocked.

Comment: as of 2021, `/users/username_available` endpoint is not available anymore

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE

> The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active.

So use
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=username

---

You can also use the API with username :

http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=tarnfeld

Will give you :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
  ...................
  <screen_name>tarnfeld</screen_name>
  <location>Portsmouth, UK</location>
  .................
  </status>
</user>
```

Or if not exist :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <request>/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=tarnfeldezf</request>
  <error>Not found</error>
</hash>
```

Comment: I think JSON URL works with 1.1 API: **https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=username**, but should use with authentication

Answer (score 4):

As API v1 is no longer available, here is another way to check if a twitter account exists. The page headers of a non existing account contain 404 (page not found).

```
function twitterAccountExists($username){
    $headers = get_headers("https://twitter.com/".$username);
    if(strpos($headers[0], '404') !== false ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't tell you the username is really available or not. Suspended and removed pages return 404 status code

Answer (score 3):

Here is how it works on PHP :

```
$user_infos = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name='.$username;

if (!@fopen($user_infos, 'r'))
{
return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, close to what sferik has posted.

```
def twitter_user_exists?(user)
   Twitter.user(user)
   true
rescue Twitter::Error::NotFound
   false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to grab the `http://twitter.com/username` page and read the response to see if you get the "Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!" page.

#### Edit:

As @Pablo Fernandez mentioned in a comment, it will be better (faster, more reliable) to check the response header, which  will be "404 not-found" if the user doesn't exist.

Comment: I once had an interesting online discussion with someone who was complaining that Twitter or some similar service would tell you which of the username or the password you had entered was wrong, which was in his opinion bad security design. This was exactly what I said.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq: I think it's more of a positive thing that Twitter lets you see what other people are posting without forcing you to sign up yourself.

Comment: @Bill rather than check "Sorry that page doesn't exist" I would check the http response code, that in that case is **404 not-found**

Comment: @Pablo: That will definitely be more reliable.  I didn't bother to check and hadn't realized that was a custom 404 page.

Comment: Yeah neither did I because it definitely doesn't seem a 404 page, had to firebug it too :)

Comment: Just checked this (April 2020) and Twitter returns 200 OK even if the user does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ruby, you could install the twitter gem and then define the following method:

```
require 'twitter'

def user_exists?(user)
  Twitter.user(user)
  true
rescue Twitter::NotFound
  false
end
```

Then, simply pass in a Twitter user name or id to your method, like so:

```
user_exists?("sferik") #=> true
user_exists?(7505382) #=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
<?php
$user = "toneid";
$contents = @file_get_contents('http://www.twitter.com/'.$user);
if (!$contents) {
    // Report error
    echo "Not a valid user";
    } else {
    // If is a valid url
    echo "OK!";
} 
?>
```