# Get a Twitter user with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter

I just want to validate that a Twitter user exists. My code is returning 401 Unauthorised with this

```
$("#getUsr").click(
    function()
    {
        var FindUser = $('#frmTwitter').val();
        $.getJSON(
            'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/' + FindUser + '.json?callback=?', 
            function(json) {
                console.log(json);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you get the url from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get that URI from?

Use instead:

```
'http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=' + FindUser
```

See API doc on [users/show](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/show)

Comment: no idea where that URL came from! still had to add &callback=? though

Comment: If you want it as a callback, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=" + user_name

You can also look at this post: [Check if twitter username exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845243/check-if-twitter-username-exists)

Answer (score 0):

All of Twitters API's require you to first authenticate with them.

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth

Comment: All API methods *support* authentication, however not all *require* it. For example, you can call users/show without authenticating.