# Check if Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn username(email) already exists

Tags: java, facebook, oauth, twitter-oauth, spring-social

In my website I want to check if emailId the user types in is associated with any of Twitter/Facebook/LinkedIn.

Searching on got me in touch with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845243/check-if-twitter-username-exists). I found accepted answer would help me for the twitter case.. But the email parameter is deprecated by twitter,

Is there any way to check and accomplish the thing I am trying to do for any or all of the Twitter/Facebook/LinkedIn?

Comment: If this capability were offered, it sounds like the type of thing that would be abused.  There's a reason MTAs don't send 'undeliverable' responses anymore for invalid addresses.

Answer (score 3):

This is only currently available with Facebook.  You would call the graph API with any access token with this url: [/search?q=zuck@fb.com&type=user](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=search?q=zuck@fb.com&type=user).  Twitter killed this from their API and LinkedIn never had it as part of their public API.